# Session not writing when redirecting

Tags: php, session-variables, php-7

EDIT:
I've found the problem, this has been done in some legacy code and for some reason there was a `session_write_close()` call in a different part of the code which closed the session before i wrote to the session.

I've been making a little php class to write to the session(mostly for single request things) and i've been having trouble writing to the session.
When i write to the session it looks like it's working and i can see it in xdebug, then i try to redirect back to the other page but when i get into the new request it is not saved to the session.

I write to the session like this:

```
public function flash($key, $value = null)
{
    if (is_null($value)) {
        return $this->flash[$key];
    }
    $_SESSION['flash'][$key] = $value;
}
```

and then redirect like this:

```
session_write_close();
header('Location: ' . $location, true, $status);
exit;
```

I can't seem to figure out why the session variable doesn't save, the `session_write_close()` function returns `false` so i know it isn't saving. But when i don't use the redirect it does save.
EDIT: the session gets started on every request using `session_start()`

I hope someone knows what might be happening and can help me.
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
With `session_status()` i get a return value of `1` which according to the documentation means `PHP_SESSION_NONE` or `sessions are enabled, but none exists` but i can see that other session values have been set and saved.

I've checked the session id and if it is the same as the one in my cookies, these are identical. I've also tries writing to the session outside the class/method and that also seems to work and i tried to set the header without the statuscode to see if that changed something but it doesn't.

Comment: Diagnosis Steps: Check writing data to the session outside of the class, does that work? Check that the session file on your server contains the same data, or is a new session generated (check `session_name()`). Try if `header` works without the $status variable.

Comment: Open the dev-tools in your browser and run this command: `document.cookie` to make sure your browser was save the cookie with session `id`. It looks like `PHPSESID`.

Comment: thank you for your ideas, i've checked and changed the post accordingly.

Comment: I have found the issue and updated the question, thanks to everyone who helped :)